# Unable to plot other plots with for loop plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am having difficulties plotting data when using a for loop.

What I want to do is combine the following two plots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x1, y1, color='blue', label='Series 1')
ax.scatter(x2, y2, color='green', label='Series 2')
```

Which gives:
[image]

And:

A second plot that uses the x1,x2,y1,y2 data but has been filtered to create a line between two points that have same y1==y2 and their x1 > x2.

```
for x1, x2, y1, y2 in special:
    ax.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
```

That gives:
[image]

I tried using `plt.fill_between` but it seems I can't use it with scatter or I don't know how to use it properly.

What I get in the end is only the scatter with the lines on my screen and I want to put those lines into the scatter plot where I can see the points that do not have the line. Basically to combine them into one...

Here is the sample data if you want to experiment:

```
x1 = [datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 3, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 3, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 3, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 3, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 3, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 3, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 7, 6, 57, 13), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 11, 5, 57, 14), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 11, 5, 57, 14), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 12, 16, 57, 4), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 12, 16, 57, 4)]

x2 = [datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 23, 2, 38, 55), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 25, 5, 26, 27), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 25, 6, 26, 27), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 16, 46, 48), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 29, 12, 53, 11), datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 31, 15, 25, 33), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 2, 5, 40, 26), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 18, 36, 11), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 18, 36, 11), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 6, 2, 21, 47), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 7, 6, 54, 1), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 11, 5, 47, 34), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 12, 16, 32, 35), datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 12, 17, 6, 9),
 datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 19, 1, 46, 29)]

y1 = ['bda3fa6c0e47be8fb2af68889a76fb7b', '86bcdeef6510f5c129c036a7446c5d20', '45249523a3866a65c30daec40fff68ca', '653e4c7b5f77a81513cbe557554c79c3', '1e6358c3e2be89cf4aabbdc792de64d2', '42249fa0ce3f09182a51c4a91bf7ebd8', '4aba3f7340769eccf0ded01f1e557b98', 'eadc80f6ca1d4c3fccf94fcc202f66ff', '9f9fd071d04150f60783841b6669c48d', 'febea981a7bc1935a9bd97e6aec11f64', 'ac1590025eb4791909fd027c02e5288f']

y2 = ['653e4c7b5f77a81513cbe557554c79c3', 'febea981a7bc1935a9bd97e6aec11f64', 'ac1590025eb4791909fd027c02e5288f', '61806b2fe0aad80e37057e32c3263886', '4aba3f7340769eccf0ded01f1e557b98', '45249523a3866a65c30daec40fff68ca', 'ce07499ecb1e7c34f5c4df8fcb638856', '751d8f2ddd2262244f24c2bca8d86fdf', '46532398219ddd7b2c0e0466ecc00985', '9668ee6dd65b606af2089bd643b313c7', '1e6358c3e2be89cf4aabbdc792de64d2', '9a3755b1dced8a4f56918e5322a12dd2', 'c3e74c8067d21a9928d7ba2d1df8bec2', '9d09a0bc49064fb76cdc0e3f016aa591', 'bda3fa6c0e47be8fb2af68889a76fb7b']

special = [['2023-04-06 03:58:32',  '2023-03-31 15:25:33',  '45249523a3866a65c30daec40fff68ca',  '45249523a3866a65c30daec40fff68ca'], ['2023-04-06 03:58:32',  '2023-03-23 02:38:55',  '653e4c7b5f77a81513cbe557554c79c3',  '653e4c7b5f77a81513cbe557554c79c3'], ['2023-04-07 06:57:13',
 '2023-03-29 12:53:11',  '4aba3f7340769eccf0ded01f1e557b98',  '4aba3f7340769eccf0ded01f1e557b98'],
 ['2023-04-12 16:57:04',  '2023-03-25 05:26:27',  'febea981a7bc1935a9bd97e6aec11f64',  'febea981a7bc1935a9bd97e6aec11f64'], ['2023-04-12 16:57:04',  '2023-03-25 06:26:27',  'ac1590025eb4791909fd027c02e5288f',  'ac1590025eb4791909fd027c02e5288f']]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're plotting string data? Matplotlib doesn't interpret strings, it will just plot them in the order it sees them in the list.

Comment: Similar to what Jared said, your data in `x1` and `x2` is dates as datetimes while your data in `special` is dates as strings. Trying to plot a mix of dates as datetimes and dates as strings won't work.